# AbstractMethodError after adding in-app update

Tags: android, in-app-update, google-play-core

My app is crashing after I've added [in-app updates](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/in-app-updates) and the play core library. Any ideas?

I'm using `implementation "com.google.android.play:core:1.6.1"` and the following code:

```
private val appUpdateManager by lazy { AppUpdateManagerFactory.create(this) }

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    appUpdateManager.appUpdateInfo.addOnSuccessListener { appUpdateInfo ->
        if (appUpdateInfo.updateAvailability() == UpdateAvailability.UPDATE_AVAILABLE
            && appUpdateInfo.isUpdateTypeAllowed(AppUpdateType.IMMEDIATE)
        ) {
            appUpdateManager.startUpdateFlowForResult(
                appUpdateInfo,
                AppUpdateType.IMMEDIATE,
                this,
                REQUEST_CODE_APP_UPDATE
            )
        }
    }
}
```

It crashes right away with the following exception:

```
2019-06-27 09:42:10.320 10700-10771/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AppUpdateService
    Process: com.example.app, PID: 10700
    java.lang.AbstractMethodError: abstract method "void com.google.android.play.core.internal.n.a()"
        at com.google.android.play.core.internal.n.run(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
```

---

Here's the app's `build.gradle`:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-android-extensions'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
    id 'com.github.triplet.play' version '2.2.1'
    id 'realm-android'
    id 'io.fabric'
    id 'com.google.android.gms.oss-licenses-plugin'
}

if (!project.hasProperty('devBuild')) {
    apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-perf'
}

def buildNumber = 36888

android {
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example"
        versionCode buildNumber
        versionName "1.8.11"

        resConfigs "en", "de"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release

            proguardFiles fileTree('./proguardrules').asList().toArray()
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    packagingOptions {
        pickFirst  'META-INF/*'
    }
}

androidExtensions {
    experimental = true
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

    implementation "androidx.cardview:cardview:$versions.androidx.cardview"
    implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:$versions.androidx.constraint_layout"
    implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:$versions.androidx.core_ktx"
    implementation "androidx.drawerlayout:drawerlayout:$versions.androidx.drawerlayout"
    implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:$versions.androidx.fragment_ktx"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:$versions.androidx.lifecycle"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:$versions.androidx.lifecycle"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:$versions.androidx.lifecycle"
    implementation "androidx.preference:preference:$versions.androidx.preference"
    implementation "androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:$versions.androidx.work"
    implementation "com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:$versions.material_dialogs"
    implementation "com.afollestad.material-dialogs:input:$versions.material_dialogs"
    implementation "com.afollestad:vvalidator:$versions.vvalidator"
    implementation "com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:$versions.crashlytics.core"
    implementation "com.google.android.material:material:$versions.androidx.material"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:$versions.play_services.location"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:$versions.play_services.maps"
    implementation "com.google.android.play:core:$versions.play_services.core"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:$versions.firebase.core"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-config:$versions.firebase.config"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:$versions.firebase.perf"
    implementation "com.xwray:groupie:$versions.groupie"
    implementation "com.xwray:groupie-kotlin-android-extensions:$versions.groupie"
    implementation "net.danlew:android.joda:$versions.joda_time_android"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$versions.kotlin.core"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:$versions.kotlin.coroutines"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:$versions.kotlin.coroutines"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-commons:$versions.anko"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-coroutines:$versions.anko"
}

play {
    serviceAccountCredentials = file('api-abc.json')
    defaultToAppBundles = true
    track = 'internal'
}

// Add to the bottom of the file
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Can you share your app.gradle please?

Comment: Sure, question is updated with the app's `build.gradle`.

Comment: Checking the issue.

Comment: Updates: When compiling a release version locally, there are no crashes. It seems that this starts to happen when I install and start the version provided via the Play Store (published as an App Bundle via `com.github.triplet.play`).

Comment: Can you try with minifyEnabled false in your gradle once.

Comment: Now its getting weird. Downloading the AAB from the Play Store Console, extracting and installing it directly to the device via BundleTool is working (using the debug keystore). So I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Using `minifyEnabled false` does not help. I first thought it's a ProGuard problem but then using a (local) release build shouldn't have worked.

Comment: Yes.  You are right

Comment: Sry, `minifyEnabled false` *does* help (I was getting a cached download). If this is a ProGuard problem, why is my locally compiled release version with `minifyEnabled true` working? And is there any documentation that I need a ProGuard rule for this (and how does it look like)?

Comment: Great. I will share soon

Comment: You're gonna love it. Changed nothing (minified enabled etc.) and just published again - works like a charm. No crashes, no special tricks. Seems like a heisenbug. Thx for the help.

Comment: Haha. Awesome :D